Issue with Clang Tools on Windows using Cygwin64 for a C++17 project with <mutex>
I want to edit a C++17 linux posix project under Windows 11 in QtCreator 13.1 and benefit from clangd and clang-tidy (LLVM version 17.0.1) there. I don't really need to be able to compile, I do that under linux. For this purpose, I'm using Cygwin64, and my C++ project loads (via cmake 3.28) all cpp files into the IDE. However, when I use <mutex> from the STL, I encounter issues with the Cygwin-GCC header. As a result, the clang tools become unusable for these use cases. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and is there a workaround for this in case of a bug? I could use libc++-devel 8.0.1-1, which seems to have at least no problems with mutex and thread_local, but I would like to use the gcc headers, since I use exactly these to compile my project under Linux.
Installed Cygwin64-Package:
gcc-g++ 13.2.1+20240426-0.1

CMake:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(TestApp LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE "C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/include/c++")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE "C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE "C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/include/c++/backward")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE "C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/include")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} SYSTEM PRIVATE "C:/cygwin64/usr/include")
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE _GNU_SOURCE)

Clang-Tidy-Call:
D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\clang\bin\clang-tidy.exe "-config={}" "-checks=-clang-diagnostic-*" "-export-fixes=C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-FUhJZO\clangtools-RtucjL\report-main.cpp-kMraAe" D:\Projecs\TestApp\main.cpp -- -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-unknown-warning-option -Wno-documentation-unknown-command -w -nostdinc -nostdinc++ -g "-std=c++17" "-fdiagnostics-color=always" -fsyntax-only -m64 "--target=x86_64-pc-cygwin" -x c++ -D_GNU_SOURCE -ID:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\share\qtcreator\cplusplus\wrappedMingwHeaders -IC:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++ -IC:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++\x86_64-pc-cygwin -IC:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++\backward -IC:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include -isystem \usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++ -isystem \usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++\x86_64-pc-cygwin -isystem \usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++\backward -isystem D:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\clang\lib\clang\17\include -isystem C:\cygwin64\usr\include -isystem \usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13........\include\w32api
C++-Example:
#include <mutex>
int main(){ return 0; }

Results in:
main.cpp:1:10: In included file: thread-local storage is not supported for the current target
C:\cygwin64\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-cygwin\13\include\c++/mutex:823:10: note: error occurred here
Mutex-header: (The last line is triggering the error)
...
...
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS
  /// Flag type used by std::call_once
  struct once_flag
  {
    constexpr once_flag() noexcept = default;

    /// Deleted copy constructor
    once_flag(const once_flag&) = delete;
    /// Deleted assignment operator
    once_flag& operator=(const once_flag&) = delete;

  private:
    // For gthreads targets a pthread_once_t is used with pthread_once, but
    // for most targets this doesn't work correctly for exceptional executions.
    __gthread_once_t _M_once = __GTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

    struct _Prepare_execution;

    template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
      friend void
      call_once(once_flag& __once, _Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args);
  };

  /// @cond undocumented
# ifdef _GLIBCXX_HAVE_TLS
  // If TLS is available use thread-local state for the type-erased callable
  // that is being run by std::call_once in the current thread.
  extern __thread void* __once_callable; //HERE <- 823:10

